# What is the difference from using bat and cmd?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have tried Google, but perhaps Google mojo is bad, since I have not found and suitable explanation

I have a batch file that stops and starts some services.
This batch file is then scheduled in task scheduler using a service account.

If I change the extension from .bat to .cmd then the script fails, since the user does not appear to have the rights to stop and start a service.

But why does this change behavior just by changing the extension of the script?

Comment: It shouldn't. Does anything else change?

Comment: This has been discussed [on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd) with a good answer.

Comment: Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I did not explicit mention that I am in a Windows 2008 R2 Server.

I the time since, I have come to the conclusion, that my errors might not relate to bat vs cmd, but the TaskScheduler itself, and if you Google that, you’ll find a whole new bag of issues.

Also thanks to @Alesito for the link to StackOverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What is the difference from using bat and cmd?

> <sub>BAT was created to interact with COMMAND.COM, the command interpreter
>   of DOS. Microsoft adopted most of the DOS commands into their new
>   interpreter named CMD. EXE. CMD was created to interface with CMD.EXE
>   and it breaks compatibility with COMMAND.COM. Another key difference
>   is in how they handle the errorlevel variable. When using BAT, this
>   variable is only changed once an actual error occurs and no change in
>   state occurs when the each command executes successfully. This is not
>   true for CMD as the errorlevel variable would still change state even
>   if no errors occur. Programmers should take note of this when creating
>   elaborate scripts as it may cause a little bit of confusion.</sub>
>
> <sub>Aside from those minor differences, CMD and BAT are identical to each
>   other. Most users who create simple scripts to clear or transfer files
>   around should not encounter any problem. For users of the more recent
>   versions of Windows, BAT and CMD are pretty much interchangeable as
>   CMD.EXE would interpret and execute the commands in both files.
>   Although most users are aware of this fact, a lot of the older people
>   who had a chance to work with DOS and its batch files still use the
>   BAT extension; simply out of habit and familiarity.</sub>
>
> > <sub>Summary:</sub>
> >
> > <sub>1. The BAT extension is used by DOS and Windows while the CMD extension is for Windows NT Command Scripts</sub>
> >
> > <sub>2. The BAT extension can be interpreted by COMMAND.COM and CMD.EXE while the CMD extension can only be interpreted by CMD.EXE</sub>
> >
> > <sub>3. The errorlevel always changes state in CMD but only on errors in BAT</sub>
>
> [source](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-cmd-and-bat/)

---

### If I change the extension from .bat to .cmd then the script fails

In order to fully give you an accurate answer on this portion of your question, the logic you are using needs to be disclosed in order to understand what it's doing to help troubleshoot.

Otherwise, I would assume the failure you are seeing has to do with how the `.CMD` scripts handle errorlevel differences or perhaps some Group Policy or other restrictions that affects the interpretation by `CMD.exe` and not when run and interpreted by `COMMAND.COM`.

---

### Further Resources

- [Difference Between CMD and BAT](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-cmd-and-bat/)
- [WWoIT - Difference between bat and cmd](http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.com/2008/08/difference-between-bat-and-cmd.html)
- [StackOverflow - Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd)
- [TechNet - What's the difference between a .cmd and a .bat file?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/38556438-550f-4578-8c97-19e272157a40/whats-the-difference-between-a-cmd-and-a-bat-file?forum=ITCG)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer    
As mentioned above, I have come to the conclusion that strange behavoiur is more relared to the configuration in TaskScheduler that the differences between bat and cmd (unless there is some differences to the elevated rights between cmd and command).    
I ended up adding some eventlogging to my script, that can found [here](https://gist.github.com/Verakso/f6b9c345d755559245f0cb67f641cbf1). That way it was easier for me to spot if the script did actually run.