# How can I delete all folders whose names are SoftwareDistribution.bak?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.bak\"
```

The above will delete a single folder: SoftwareDistribution.bak. 
How can I delete all folders whose names are SoftwareDistribution.bak? For example, SoftwareDistribution.bak1, SoftwareDistribution.bak3, SoftwareDistribution.bak2, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rmdir won't accept wildcards, so you have to enumerate the dirs first

```
for /D %A in (C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.bak*) Do @RMDir /S /Q "%A"
```

For security reasons I'd omit the /Q switch while testing.
In a batch file change `%A` to `%%A`

Comment: Do you mean the following? It did not work. No files were deleted. `for /D %A in (C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.bak*) Do @RMDir /S "%A"`
`rmdir /s /q "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.bak\"`

Comment: Didn't I write: in a batch file change %A to %%A?

Comment: I don't want it to ask me for confirmation before deletion. What should I do?

Comment: Once you are shure only desired folders are removed, reinsert the `/Q`

Comment: Do you mean this `for /Q /D %A in (C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.bak*) Do @RMDir /S "%A"`?

Comment: No `rmdir /s /q %%A`

Comment: Thanks, it works now, although I use it in a .cmd file rather than a .bat file.

Comment: That is nearly the same. There are only [subtle differences](https://superuser.com/questions/1195624/what-is-the-difference-from-using-bat-and-cmd)

Comment: An off-topic question: do you know why those `SoftwareDistribution.bak` backup folders are created?

Comment: See [this anwer to the topic](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/is-it-safe-to-delete-files-under/8d98d924-b0b1-4f2b-bb4b-13f38126c588)

Comment: Your link makes no mention of .bak files.

Comment: Sorry wrong link. [Cite from this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/softwaredistributionbak/b27f1d3d-54ef-4e2a-a2a4-fc08d8b2b958)
The Software Distribution folder holds the history files from Windows updates. When you do a Windows update after removing the folder, it will recreate the folder each time. It will not affect any updates that are already installed or future updates. Update information is added to this folder each time an update is run. Deleting the folder will not cause any problems. ...